# Swift - convert date string from a "datepicker filled date field" to nsdate

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

Ive got a UIDatepicker attached to a text field named dateField. when the user clicks on the field, a UIDatePicker pops up and the user chooses a date of birth. That date is saved as a string to that dateField and shows up formatted according to the users location ie May 4 1990 in USA or 4 May 1990 in Australia.

Later when they press a save button, I want to save the date to CoreData. I've been trying to convert the date string back to an NSDate but i keep running into problems and getting a nil date.

I believe in need to set the NSDateFormatter locale and timezone before doing this so i set it to the user's currentLocale and localTimeZone. I also believe I need to set a date format ... if i set the date format to "dd MMM yyyy" the NSDate works if the users locale is Australia but not if i set the locale to USA.

How can i set the date format so that it allows the dateFromString method to work regardless of the user's locale. Or should i be doing this differently (ie save a birthdate as a String rather than an NSDate unique point in time)

my code

```
    let dateStr = "20 Aug 1990" //suppose dateField contains this string as saved from a UIDatePicker (formatted according to the user's locale ... ie would be Aug 20 1990 in USA locale)
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy" //how can i set this to be non-locale specific

    var dobStr = dobField.text
    var dob: NSDate? = formatter.dateFromString(dobStr)
    println(dob) //prints nil if user locale is USA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've fixed it. I think the thing that was causing problem was that I was setting locale to currentLocale but then 2 lines down specifying a dateFormat which would work if it corresponds to the current locale but not otherwise. Anyway, fix appears to be just specify locale and let that setting dictate the format used.

Answer (score 2):

```
let date: Date = myDatePicker.date
```

I haven't tested it, but [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDatePicker/date) suggest it should work.